# Java Swing: Making a panel to want to be as wide as possible

Tags: java, user-interface, swing

At my JFrame I'd like to have a dashboard on the right and a custom canvas, where I will draw stuff on the left. The dashboard needs to be fixed width and canvas take the rest. So here is what I do in the JFrame constructor.

```
getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
JPanel leftPanel = new JPanel();
JPanel rightPanel = new JPanel();
rightPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
leftPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.EAST, rightPanel);
getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.CENTER, leftPanel);

rightPanel.add(new JLabel("Label1"));
rightPanel.add(new JLabel("Label2"));
rightPanel.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(100, 200));

leftPanel.add(new CustomCanvas());
pack();
```

As a result my canvas is squeezed to width 0. 
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As a result my canvas is squeezed to width 0

Unless you add a component to a panel it will have a default size of 0, as you have noticed. When you add it to the left panel which uses a FlowLayout it is displayed at its preferred size and the left panel is resized to fill the space in the Center of the BorderLayout.

So the solution is to add your custom painting panel directly to the Center of the BorderLayout and get rid of the left panel.

Answer (score 1):

If `CustomCanvas` is a `Canvas`, I don't think you can mix AWT and Swing components like that. Maybe make `CustomCanvas` a `JPanel` instead. Also, the default layout for `JPanel` is already `FlowLayout`.

Answer (score 1):

Pack will resize everything such that everything gets at least it's preferred size.  The preferred size of a canvas is 0x0 by default.  You need to do something so that your canvas has a preferred size if you wish to use pack, such as calling setPreferredSize().

Alternately you can pack and then query the size of your right panel, and set the width of your frame to some addition minimal width appropriate for the canvas area (though setting a preferred size will be easier and better).

Also, don't mix the AWT (Canvas) components with Swing; you likely want to use a JPanel or JComponent for your canvas.